# How to Embed React/Angular application in a widget popup style

Tags: javascript, reactjs, widget, embed, web-component

So this is more a design/tooling question (no code to show)

### The Idea:

I have an idea for a web app that I'd like to implement using either React/Angular depending on the outcome of this discussion really. The idea is that I want to be able to bundle up my web application and embed it in any website with as little code as possible. The end result for the website it's embedded on would be a new 'widget style' button hovering in the corner which when clicked opened up my new React/Angular application in a pop up or layover modal style window.

To be clear, I want to, if possible provide the clients host website with as little code as possible such as:

```
<script src="https://myappurl.js"><script>
<some-new-element-in-html-body?> </some-new-element-in-html-body?>
```

This would then leave them with a widget style button that when clicked opened my app as a layover

### The How:

Now I know there are probably a few ways of implementing this. I come from an Angular development background as a full stack dev so embedding apps within websites would be a new concept to me. I guess the outcome I want is similar to that of a chat widget application on a website.I'm struggling to find online the best solution or toolset for the job.

**Web components** seem to have popped up quite a lot. This would result in me having to provide the website with the  tag and the new html element but could this then add a widget style button which triggered the application popup. I've also read that React/Angular bundle sizes may be too much for web components, even in smaller apps, so something like preact may be preferred? Again the same question above stands. This youtube video explains preact/react web components and wonder if its the best option - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PUGDzA1uP-Y&t=545s

**iFrames** are definitely an option if I wanted to simply mount my application with any other website. That said its not really what I'm after, as although I want the contained app, I also want to be able to add this custom widget style button to the host website, without having to edit the website directly.

**UMD Libraries** - again something else I've come accross but this is the most unclear, and how they differ or would benefit my specific scenario compared to web-components.Now I may be barking up the wrong tree completely, and if so could you kind people please point me in the right direction of what I should be looking at.

I may also need to consider 2 apps, one for rendering a button that loaded quickly annd then facilitated the popup / modal type layover, and then one which loaded up my application with one of the 3 methods mentioned above?

THANKYOU IN ADVANCE! :)

Comment: I reworded it to hopefully make it clearer. Wasnt aware this was a problem?

Comment: If you gave someone half an answer, and that person throws it into the bin. How would you feel? ... nuff said..

Comment: Well unfortunately I still have the problem so I'm asking for help. Thanks :)

Comment: @jjharrison I'm facing the same scenario and I have the same doubts. Could you solve it? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: @MauroBarrionuevo tbh I'm not a FE dev so all the tech was new to me. I never found a solution that satisfied both bundle size and functionality I needed although I'm sure a solution is out there